# Cargo contract 3.0.1

Tags: ink, cargo

Ink! 3.1.0 has been released today, and it seems that it has been automatically embed/used in the cargo-contract command.
The result is that newly compiled contract are no more compatible with node that run 3.0 contracts pallet.

Is there a way to keep version 3.0.1 when compiling ink! contracts ?

Thanks for your help !

Edit : found the `-Z original-manifest` cargo-contract option that preserves `cargo.toml` versions values :)
But the build failed at the metadata generation...

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Download and uncompress precompile contract node [v0.13](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases/tag/v0.13.0)
- Launch dev node :

```
./substrate-contracts-node-v0.13 --dev
```

- Build flipper contract sample :

```
cargo contract new flipper
cd flipper
cargo +nightly contract build
```

- Use [Contracts UI](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/) to instantiate the flipper contract
- Instantiation failed with 'ExtrinsicFailed'
- Debug log shows :

```
DEBUG ThreadId(46) runtime::contracts: CodeRejected: module imports a
  non-existent function
```

Same contract is instantiated correctly on recent contracts node v0.14 and v0.15.

Same flipper contract built a few days before (using ink! 3.0.1), instantiation is correct on v0.13.

I saw that upgrading my [node version to polkadot v0.9.22](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/releases/tag/v3.1.0) should resolve this issue. But the cumulus pallet is still on polkadot v0.9.20.

That's why I asked initially how to stick to ink! 3.0.1 when compiling contract.

Comment: Can you please include more details about how you set up your project and the specific error you are facing?

Comment: Thanks @ShawnTabrizi and Alexander, I just added some informations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try hardcoding `version = "=3.0.1"`?

The `"=x.x.x"` will pin this very version.

Comment: You're the boss @cmichi !  
With `version = "=3.0.1"`, contract are instantiated correctly in node v0.13.  
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just want to add that I experienced the same issue (trying to deploy other example contracts) and it was solved as @cmichi said.

Comment: @cmichi weirdly I am getting `error[E0061]: this function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied, an argument of type ExecuteConstructorConfig is missing` on constructors using `version = "=3.0.1"`

Comment: others are experiencing same issue: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2870/cargo-contract-throws-error-about-supplied-arguments-in-inkconstructor-f

Comment: Add one more dependency in Cargo.toml
`ink_lang_codegen = { version = "=3.0.1", default-features = false }`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the issue reporting! Its origin is that with ink! `3.1.0` a number of backwards incompatible changes were introduced. That unpleasant mistake is now [fixed](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1284) and with ink! `3.3.0` release being published everything should work smoothly again even for contracts using ink! `3.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of transitive dependencies (pallets that ink pallets themselves depend on), as you can check by inspecting Cargo.lock - it will pull the most recent versions for those (3.2.0 as of now). That is because for the Cargo resolver these are within the semver compatibility range (when in fact they are not compatible, they contain non-compatible, breaking changes).

For now you might try to explicitely lock the version of ink_lang_codegen too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hardcode `version = "3.0.1"` in all `ink_*` dependencies in your contract's `Cargo.toml` file?

Comment: Thanks Artur, that's what I did, but no luck... The first step of the build (1/5 dev [unoptimized + debuginfo]) is using 3.0.1, but the release build (2/5) is using 3.1.0.

Comment: Please add a link in your original posting to the repo which you try to compile. Can't really help without the code.

Comment: Could you try hardcoding `version = "=3.0.1"` in your `Cargo.toml`? The `"=x.x.x"` will pin this very version.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error and was able to get rid of it by upgrading the [substrate contracts node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) from `0.12.0` to `0.14.0`.

Here's a more detailed view of my setup in an issue [on github](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1253#issuecomment-1124958646)