# cargo contract throws error about supplied arguments in ` #[ink(constructor)]` for version 3.0.1

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cargo, cargo-contract

In my smart contract, all the ink dependencies are set to **`=3.0.1`** because of this issue:
[Cargo contract 3.0.1](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2721/cargo-contract-3-0-1)

When I tried to execute the `cargo contract build` or even `cargo +nightly contract build` to the flipper project, it results into this error:

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied
  --> lib.rs:18:9
   |
18 | /         /// Constructor that initializes the `bool` value to the given `init_value`.
19 | |         #[ink(constructor)]
20 | |         pub fn new(init_value: bool) -> Self {
21 | |             Self { value: init_value }
22 | |         }
   | |         ^
   | |         |
   | |_________supplied 1 argument
   |           expected 2 arguments
   |
note: function defined here
  --> /home/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_lang-3.0.1/src/codegen/dispatch/execution.rs:81:8
   |
81 | pub fn execute_constructor<Contract, F, R>(
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0061]: this function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied
  --> lib.rs:24:9
   |
24 | /         /// Constructor that initializes the `bool` value to `false`.
25 | |         ///
26 | |         /// Constructors can delegate to other constructors.
27 | |         #[ink(constructor)]
28 | |         pub fn default() -> Self {
29 | |             Self::new(Default::default())
30 | |         }
   | |         ^
   | |         |
   | |_________supplied 1 argument
   |           expected 2 arguments
   |
note: function defined here
  --> /home/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_lang-3.0.1/src/codegen/dispatch/execution.rs:81:8
   |
81 | pub fn execute_constructor<Contract, F, R>(
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0061`.
error: could not compile `flipper` due to 2 previous errors
Error: Compilation failed with toolchain `nightly-2022-03-14-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Caused by:
    command failed: "cargo" "check" "--target-dir" "/home/projects/flipper/target/dylint/target/nightly-2022-03-14-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--manifest-path" "/home/projects/flipper/Cargo.toml"
ERROR: `"/home/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "dylint" "--lib" "ink_linting" "--manifest-path=/home/projects/flipper/Cargo.toml"` failed with exit code: Some(1)
```

I'm at my wit's end.
(I would like to specify that the substrate runtime is for ***`polkadot-v0.9.18`***)

---

To replicate:

- I am using `rustc 1.63.0-nightly (4cbaac699 2022-05-25)`
- The `cargo contract` version is ***1.4***.
- The smart contract is the flipper:`cargo contract new flipper`
- And then in the ***.toml*** file:

```
[package]
name = "flipper"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["[your_name] <[your_email]>"]
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ink_primitives = { version = "=3.0.1", default-features = false }
ink_metadata = { version = "=3.0.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
ink_env = { version = "=3.0.1", default-features = false }
ink_storage = { version = "=3.0.1", default-features = false }
ink_lang = { version = "=3.0.1", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

[lib]
name = "flipper"
path = "lib.rs"
crate-type = [
    # Used for normal contract Wasm blobs.
    "cdylib",
]

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink_metadata/std",
    "ink_env/std",
    "ink_storage/std",
    "ink_primitives/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, weirdly enough this was working 3 days ago on 3.0.1

Comment: Can you please post a minimal reproducer repo?

Comment: @mastro we're the same! It was working 2 days ago for me!.
@AlexanderTheißen I used cargo contract 1.4, and I used 
`cargo contract new flipper` , then changed all versions to `"=3.0.1"`

Comment: If you're using the substrate contracts node, you can [try to update it to get rid of the `module imports a non-existent function` error](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1253#issuecomment-1124958646).

Comment: @forgetso I can't upgrade to v0.9.22 because my substrate node will ultimately use orml currencies and tokens, and the latest update is still using `polkadot-v0.9.19`

Comment: This is super strange, what does `cargo contract --version` output? Could you try it with the latest `cargo-contract` v1.4.0?

Comment: did you guys managed to get it working?

Comment: @cmichi yes it's v1.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same situation above.
After specify indirect dependencies' version declaratively, I succeded to compile and deploy contracts to the local node with pallet-contracts polkadot-v0.9.19 support.

Please try to add below to Cargo.toml dependencies section.

```
ink_lang_codegen = { version = "=3.0.0", default-features = false }
```

I don't know exactly why and what was the breaking change. I'd like to know if someone knows it in detail. and other potential workarounds.

Comment: well i changed to `=3.0.1` and it works! You are my hero! My savior! Thanks @Shunsuke!

@mastro try it: 
`ink_lang_codegen = {version = "=3.0.1", default-features = false}`

Answer (score 3):

I've reproduced your issue and I believe it was an error on our end which caused this. It
looks like we introduced a breaking change in the codegen as part of ink! 3.2, sorry!

This change was related to the `execute_constructor` method of the `ink_lang` crate. In [#1264](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1267/files#diff-80ef02562d51e36365db131b242217f4ea2f5b4542df737f46950fafb442b2dbL81)
we removed one of the arguments, which is what's causing this error.

Now, to break it down a little more. Let's consider the error you're getting:

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied
```

The dependency graph looks something like this (taken from the `Cargo.lock`):

- name = "ink_lang", version = "3.0.1"
- name = "ink_lang_codegen",  version = "3.2.0"

The `ink_lang_codegen@3.2.0` crate gets pulled in transitively by the `ink_lang_macro@3.0.1`
crate (you can use `cargo tree` to more easily spot this) because according to SemVer
3.2.0 is compatible with 3.0.1.

The `ink_lang_codegen@3.2.0` crate [generates code as follows](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/809a113a03868688da7258f7ba6f460507b097dd/crates/lang/codegen/src/generator/dispatch.rs#L556):

```rust
quote_spanned!(constructor_span=>
    Self::#constructor_ident(input) => {
        if #any_constructor_accept_payment && #deny_payment {
            ::ink_lang::codegen::deny_payment::<
                <#storage_ident as ::ink_lang::reflect::ContractEnv>::Env>()?;
        }

        ::ink_lang::codegen::execute_constructor::<#storage_ident, _, _>(
            move || { #constructor_callable(input) }
        )
    }
)
```

However, `ink_lang@3.0.1` (and also anything `<3.2`) exposes [the following function](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/905caa4170c79225139fc9ad00262c68393d883f/crates/lang/src/codegen/dispatch/execution.rs#L81):

```rust
pub fn execute_constructor<Contract, F, R>(
    config: ExecuteConstructorConfig,
    f: F,
) -> Result<(), DispatchError>;
```

When the Rust compiler tries to build the expanded macro code it fails because the
function from `ink_lang` doesn't match the generated code, resulting in the error you are
seeing!

By locking in the codegen at `3.0.1` you end up compiling code which is using the [correct function signature](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/905caa4170c79225139fc9ad00262c68393d883f/crates/lang/codegen/src/generator/dispatch.rs#L567).

```rust
quote_spanned!(constructor_span=>
    Self::#constructor_ident(input) => {
        ::ink_lang::codegen::execute_constructor::<#storage_ident, _, _>(
            ::ink_lang::codegen::ExecuteConstructorConfig {
                payable: #accepts_payment,
            },
            move || { #constructor_callable(input) }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: thank you @HCastano for telling us the cause of the error. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the issue reporting! Its origin is described in detail in @HCastano's answer, and is now [fixed](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1284) in the upcoming **ink! `3.3.0` release** along with other backwards compatibility breaking issues. Once the release is published, your ink! contracts (no matter on what `3.x.x` version they depend upon) should being built smoothly again (no version overrides in `Cargo.toml` required). Stay tuned and have fun!